Why does Python code run in IDE but not in CLI?
I am trying to run a Python package from my CLI using the command python main.py. It gives an error, whereas this package runs smoothly when I hit Run Code command on the main.py menu in VSCode.
I am using the same venv in VSCode as I am in my CLI. I also uninstalled and reinstalled python to see if that would help, but no luck. The following is the error I am getting when running the CLI command. I've also tried running <path to my venv> main.py and python3 main.py which both give me the same error.
Error:
Could not import the PyAudio C module 'pyaudio._portaudio'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/Developer/Audio-Processor/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import audio_processor
  File "/Users/david/Developer/Audio-Processor/audio_processor.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyaudio
  File "/Users/david/Developer/Audio-Processor/audio-processor/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/__init__.py", line 111, in <module>
    import pyaudio._portaudio as pa
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/david/Developer/Audio-Processor/audio-processor/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyaudio/_portaudio.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_PaMacCore_SetupChannelMap'

